# Setting top-level GeoJSON id using ogr2ogr?

Tags: postgis, gdal, ogr2ogr

I'd like to write the contents of a PostGIS table (or query) to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr.

How can I select an attribute and have it be used as a top-level id in the output GeoJSON, without losing it as a property?

Given some PostGIS data:

```
CREATE TABLE things (
    city_id int,
    entity_id int,
    geom geometry(Point, 4326)
);

INSERT INTO things VALUES (3, 19, 'SRID=4326;POINT (4 8)');
```

And an ogr2ogr command:

`ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" things.geojson PG:"dbname=postgres" ***magic*** things`

I'd like to see:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { 
        "type": "name", 
        "properties": { 
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" 
        }
    },                                                                           
    "features": [
    { 
        "type": "Feature",
        "id" : 19,
        "properties": { 
            "city_id": 3,  
            "entity_id": 19 
        }, 
        "geometry": { 
             "type": "Point", 
              "coordinates": [ 4.0, 8.0 ] 
        }
   }]
}
```

Note that the value of `entity_id` was copied to the top level, but the attribute was not removed from the `properties` section.

I've tried the following:

1. Set primary key to `entity_id` then run ogr2ogr with `-preserve_fid`.  This gives me a top-level "id" but removes `entity_id` from the properties.
2. Use SQL to copy the `entity_id` to another column, and then instruct ogr2ogr to use this as the id.

   ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" things.geojson PG:"dbname=postgres" 
   --config PGSQL_OGR_FID=fizz 
   -preserve_fid
   -sql "SELECT *, entity_id AS fizz FROM things"

In this case, I get no top-level id.

Tried this on GDAL 1.11.2 and current master.

Comment: I would write to gdal-dev list and ask if this ticket http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6538 is also applied for writing GeoJSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with GDAL 3.6.2. Attribute "attributefid" is first selected as name "foobar" and consumed as a GeoJSON id, and then it gets selected again with `*` and placed into GeoJSON properties.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output_with_desired_fid.json -lco id_field=foobar PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=dbname user=user password=password" -sql "select attributefid as foobar,* from test"
```